# Meaning of “a dignified disapproval”

Tags: meaning, deverbal-adjectives

> Hedwig clicked her beak with a dignified disapproval (after seeing the small owl deliver the post.)

From *Harry Potter and the Prisoner of Azkaban*

What does *dignified* mean here? How can being serious and formal make sense in this case?

Comment: Which part of the dictionary definition do you disagree with?

Comment: How can an owl click its beak in a serious and in an unserious way?

Comment: I guess one would have to use their imagination to see "dignity" in the beak-clicking of an owl.  "Dignified" in that sentence should be considered the standard definition of the word.  If you're not familiar with the Harry Potter stories, many human-like qualities are attributed to animals and magical creatures throughout the storyline.

Answer (score 1):

This is less about how Hedwig clicks her beak than it is a reflection of her personality. It's an example of anthropomorphism; the attitude is more important than its expression. By writing it this way, Rowling allows us to "see" the expression on Hedwig's face.

The context (as you pointed out) is that Hedwig feels she could have done a better, more professional job than Pigwidgeon, and feels a bit of professional embarrassment due to the little owl's antics.